# Is Hom$(G,-)$ left exact if morphisms are required to be continuous?

Tags: category-theory, topological-groups

Suppose now that the objects in question are ***abelian*** topological groups $G$ so that morphisms are ***continuous*** group homomorphisms. Given an exact sequence of abelian topological groups $0 \to G''\to G \to G''$ is the functor $\textrm{Hom}(H,-)$ a left-exact functor?  $H$ is an abelian topological group.

We know that if we only care about group homomorphisms then $\textrm{Hom}(H,-)$ is left-exact, but will the condition of ***continuity*** now change anything? It seems there is a problem because to prove exactness at $\textrm{Hom}(H,G)$ requires defining a map from $H \to G''$ which may not be continuous.

**Edit:** PinkElephants has shown us that this functor may fail to be exact. However if we consider a specific case which is the exact sequence

$$0 \to \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{R} \stackrel{e^{2\pi  i x}}{\longrightarrow } S^1 \to 0$$

then is the functor $\textrm{Hom}(S^1, -)$ left-exact? What about the *contravariant* functor $\textrm{Hom}(-,S^1)$, is it still right-exact?

Comment: If $\textrm{Hom}(G, -)$ fails to be left exact then you have defined exact sequence incorrectly.

Comment: Continuity, in any case, cannot solve anything, for you always put the discrete topology on groups!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez What if I consider $S^1$ as a topological group the topology on here is the Euclidean topology?

Comment: @ZhenLin I made an edit above.

Comment: Segal has a paper on derived functor cohomology for topological groups; I'd imagine that this is discussed in there.

Comment: @ZhenLin See the answer below for an example where it fails to be.

Comment: Let me just mention the amazing fact that if you consider only compact abelian groups, then this category actually turns out to be abelian. In particular, Hom(S^1, -) is left-exact as long as you restrict to compact groups.

Comment: $\textrm{Hom}(-, G)$ is very rarely right exact, but again, if it fails to be left exact, you have defined exact sequence incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Ben, I just stumbled over this thread: in view of the accepted answer, maybe you're interested in having a look at my expository paper on [exact categories](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2009.04.004) where I give a hands-on approach to Quillen's theory. Best wishes and a happy New Year, Theo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{Hom}$Given a short sequence
$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0,\tag{$\ast$}$$ in an additive category, the sequence of abelian groups
$$
0 \to \Hom(G,A) \xrightarrow{f_\ast} \Hom(G,B) \xrightarrow{g_\ast} \Hom(G,C)
$$
is exact for all $G$ if and only if $f$ is a kernel of $g$ and, dually,
$$
0 \to \Hom(C,G) \xrightarrow{g^\ast} \Hom(B,G) \xrightarrow{f^\ast} \Hom(A,G)
$$
is exact for all $G$ if and only if $g$ is a cokernel of $f$.

This can be interpreted as follows: Since we *want* $\Hom$ to be left exact, the minimal requirement that a short sequence $(\ast)$ in an additive category should satisfy in order to *deserve* to be called exact is that $f$ be a kernel of $g$ and that $g$ be a cokernel of $f$.

From this point of view, the example in Pink Elephant's answer is not a good one: the identity $G \to H$ is a monomorphism and an epimorphism, but it is not an isomorphism and *a fortiori* neither a kernel nor a cokernel.

The trouble of calling *all* kernel-cokernel sequences $(\ast)$ exact is that they lack the closure conditions you need in order to prove the diagram lemmas necessary for homological algebra. A particularly convenient (hence convincing) approach to exact sequences (albeit not *intrinsic* as in abelian categories) is usually attributed to Quillen, see [exact categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_category). In a nutshell what this means is that you have to think about *what* sequences you *want* to call exact.

Outside of the additive setting exactness can be dealt with in various ways but it gets even more complicated. See e.g. [Borceux-Bourn's book](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Borceux-Bourn).

Answer (score 2):

Let $H$ be an abelian topological group whose topology is not discrete, and let $G$ have the same underlying group as $H$ but with the discrete topology. Consider the short exact sequence $0\to G\to H\to 0\to 0$ where $G\to G$ is the identity on sets.

Now the sequence $0\to \mathrm{Hom}(H,G)\to \mathrm{Hom}(H,H)\to \mathrm{Hom}(H,0)$ is not exact at $\mathrm{Hom}(H,H)$, as $\mathrm{Id}_H$ is in the kernel but not the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However if the topologies are all inhereted from the euclidean topology (e.g. $G''= \Bbb{Z}$, $G = \Bbb{R}$ and $G'= S^1$) then will the functor be left-exact?

Comment: You may see my edit in the question above for further queries.